# How to check the dictionary data?

Tags: objective-c

@"noresult"Here `favData.searchDict` is a dictionary object, it consists of 3 key/value pairs, actually the data in this dictionary object is obtained dynamically from a service call. It consists of 3 strings, each string consists of either the data like "noresult" or some url like "www.gmail.com", so my requirement is, if I get the url in first string I should not check the remaining 2 strings. So if I didn't get the url in first string I have to check 2nd string, if I get the url in 2nd string no need to check 3rd string, if the first 2 strings are "noresult" then I have to check 3rd string.

I am writing code like below, this code is checking the other 2 strings even if I got the url in first string itself, so can you please suggest how to write logic for not to check the 2nd & 3rd vice versa if I get the data

```
for (id key in favData.searchDict) {
    NSLog(@"objects inside favData.searchDict is %@",[favData.searchDict objectForKey:key]);
    NSRange match = [[favData.searchDict objectForKey:key] rangeOfString:@"noresult"];
    if(match.location == NSNotFound) {
        req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithString:[favData.searchDict objectForKey:key]]]];
       [[[featuredAsset viewControler]iWebview]loadRequest:req];
    }
}
```

Comment: Break out of the for loop, but that seems to simple to be the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for (id key in favData.searchDict) {

        NSLog(@"objects inside favData.searchDict is %@",[favData.searchDict objectForKey:key]);

        NSRange match = [[favData.searchDict objectForKey:key] rangeOfString:kNoResult];
        BOOL flag;
        if (flag != YES) {
            if(match.location == NSNotFound)
            {
            req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithString:[favData.searchDict objectForKey:key]]]];
            [[[featuredAsset viewControler]iWebview]loadRequest:req];
            flag = YES;
            }

        }
    }
```

I guess it will solve your problem......

Answer (score 1):

Just `break` the loop when the condition you're looking for is met:

```
for (id key in favData.searchDict) {
    NSRange match = [[favData.searchDict objectForKey:key] rangeOfString:kNoResult];
    if (match.location == NSNotFound) {
        req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithString:[favData.searchDict objectForKey:key]]]];
       [[[featuredAsset viewControler]iWebview]loadRequest:req];
       break; /* execution will continue ... */
    }
}
/* ...here */
```

Answer (score 1):

For a more modern method, use the block based [NSDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method

```
- (void)enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop))block
```

And you can set `stop` from within the block to stop further enumeration.